# how to use the useEffect hook to initialize reducerstate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So my problem is that I want to use a function to generate my initial state and then use that generated state in my reducer.

I have this StateGenerator() function outside my App component function that returns a big array.

if I write it like this:

```
const [boardState, tileDispatchFn] = useReducer(
    tileReducer,
    StateGenerator()
  );
```

it works, but that StateGenerator() function is executed every render (is this normal??) although the state is not reset to initial situation (which is good I guess??)

But still the functions gets executed every render and its quite a big array that gets generated and if I render to fast by clicking it breaks

if I write it like this:

```
let initState = null;

useEffect(() => {
    initState = StateGenerator();
  }, []);

  const [boardState, tileDispatchFn] = useReducer(
    tileReducer,
    initState
  );
```

I get an error like this *Cannot read property ... of null* because the useEffect is executed after the render

What is the simplest way of using my StateGenerator() function to generate my initial state? what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest would be to use the third argument to `useReducer` which is an initialization function.

[useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) - `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialArg, init);`

[Lazy initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization)

> You can also create the initial state lazily. To do this, you can pass
> an `init` function as the third argument. The initial state will be set
> to `init(initialArg)`.
>
> It lets you extract the logic for calculating the initial state
> outside the reducer.

I've no idea what your state looks like but this is how it would be used.

```
const [boardState, tileDispatchFn] = useReducer(
  tileReducer,
  {              // <-- default initial board state
    // state keys with safe default values
  },
  StateGenerator // <-- state initializer function
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
this solution works to avoid that the "generator" function is executed every render, but I still need some initial state. I got it working with an almost empty initial state (by adding a lot of null checks in the code), but for now its OK.

Comment: @xvk Correct, that is part of the "default initial board state". You can either provide initial state that won't throw errors in your UI (i.e. empty arrays `[]` or strings `''`), or implement the null checks in the UI (*or a combination of both in the case of a poor state update*).

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch a action that set the initial state of the reducer. When the component mount you can dispatch the action to set the state from any component like:

```
import React from "react";
const initialState = { count: 0 };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "set_initial":
      return { count: action.payload };
    case "increment":
      return { count: state.count + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { count: state.count - 1 };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "set_initial", payload: 10 });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrement" })}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Only problem is that I still need to "hardcode" an initial state. 

Using the dispatch function in the useEffect is better than my solution, but I think that the solution of @Drew is cleaner because it essentially does the same thing but then with the init function and without the need for a useEffect hook.

although, in his solution I also need some sort of "hardcoded" initial state.